# ¿Como puedo hacer un sleep de letra por letra con bash ? Alguien me puede ayuda

Tags: bash, shell

## !/bin/bash

echo "                Bienvenido"

Comment: Puedes detallar un poco mas tu pregunta ya  que es ambigua.

Comment: Si , bueno quiero hacer un script con bash ,  casi parecido a:  " | lolcat " ,  quiero hacer cuando ponga un mensaje y lo ejecute: me salga letra por letra

Comment: Si bien la pregunta no esta del todo clara, se entiende a que va.

Comment: Bueno disculpe por no hacer tan claro,  esque recién estoy entrar en este mundo espero que me entiendan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si podes usar Python parcialmente:

```
#!/bin/bash

read  -a arrayDeLetras <<< $( python -c 'print("Bienvenido".replace(""," ")) ' )

for letter in "${arrayDeLetras[@]}"
do
    printf $letter
    sleep 1
done
```

O si solo podes usar Bash "puro" :

```
#!/bin/bash

word="Bienvenido"
for ((i=0; i < ${#word}; i++ ))
do
    printf "${word:i:1}"
    sleep 1
done
```

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Owww encerio muchísimas gracias  de todo corazón amigo , es eso lo que esta buscando , que Dios te bendiga amigo